# UITableView row height crash

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I have four types of cells. Every cell has it's own height. I'd like to set the height of the row for each table view cell but it crashes in this method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:PastEventWICellIdentifier]){
        return 56;
    }
    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:PastEventWOICellIdentifier]){
        return 56;
    }
    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:EventWICellIdentifier]){
        return 112;
    }
    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:EventWOICellIdentifier]){
        return 112;
    }
    return 56;
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: and the crash message is?

Comment: Why not differentiate the cells based on datasource property for a row, instead of calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the cells using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` inside the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, because the cells are not there yet. They will be created after their heights are set.

You may set the heights of the cells based on their location using `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this method is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so the cells don't exists. You should have a list of Height already calculated when `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called. Remember to not load all list in tableview because this method (`heightForRowAtIndexPath`) takes longer to load tableview...